# Bash - IF and && syntax?

Tags: bash

I could use a little help with my IF and && statement.  It's not working and nothing I'm trying is working either.  Maybe someone can see the issue:

```
if [[ $thisvariable="yes" && grep 'this string' ./"$thisfile".txt ]]; then
```

This just doesn't work.  Does anyone see an issue?

Comment: I've tried multiple variations, including the suggestion below:    ./script: line 146: conditional binary operator expected
    ./script.sh: line 146: syntax error near `string''
    ./script.sh: line 146: `      if [[ $thisvariable == "yes" && grep     'this string' ./"$thisfile".txt ]]; then'
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Downloads$

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if [[ "$thisvariable" = "yes" ]] && grep -q 'this string' ./"${thisfile}".txt; then
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm just now seeing the last post, so I didn't try that.  I finally got it to work with this:

```
if [ $thisvariable == yes ] && [ "`grep 'this string' ./"thisfile"`" ]; then
```

Comment: i was about to answer the same, if uses == for comparison (not =) and it uses single [] not [[]] (double)

Comment: @Faizan no, both work. In fact, `=` is more correct. The `[` and `[[` are two different things but both can work here. However, within `[[`, the `==` operator [behaves differently](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html).

Answer (score 1):

The `[` construct cannot take multiple conditions. What you are attempting can be written in multiple ways:

```
if [ "$thisvariable" = "yes" ] && grep 'this string' ./"thisfile" > /dev/null
then 
    echo yes; 
fi
```

or, more simply

```
[ "$thisvariable" = "yes" ] && grep 'this string' ./"thisfile" > /dev/null && echo yes
```

Answer (score 0):

From: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html#SCOMPARISON1

```
if [ "$a" = "$b" ]
```

Caution!, note the whitespace framing the "=".

```
if [ "$a"="$b" ] is not equivalent to the above.
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried that too.  I updated my comment above.  I've also tried (and get this error):  ./script.sh: line 146: syntax error near `string''    ./script.sh: line 146: `      if [[ $thisvariable = "yes" && grep 'this string' ./"$thisfile".txt ]]; then'